# Single variable changing over time - compare trajectories

Tags: pca, modeling

I am running an experiment in the lab where a variable is measured over time (e.g: 60 seconds)
I run several times the experiment without any disturbance.

Then I run the experiment again by introducing a disturbance in the starting conditions. The trajectory of the variable I am measuring will start in a similar way and then will behave slightly different.

My goal is to be able to identify that a disturbance was made just by looking at the trajectory.

What's the best method to make this comparison? I want to be able to say "this experiment is significantly different from the non disturbed one, so something must be wrong".

I was thinking of using some mvda techniques, such as PCA, and just use each time point as a variable, and then I can see clusters of observations. Is this a good approach?

Comment: How many times do you measure the variable over the 60 second period? Or do you collect data that is truly functional (infinite dimensional)?

Comment: the variable is measured every second. It looks like a continuous function, but the measurement is made at discrete points.

Comment: @zelite: And at which moment in time do you want to make the decision about whether there was a disturbance or not? Continuously, or only once you have the whole trajectory? Also: how many disturbed/non-disturbed trials do you have?

Comment: I have around 20 experiments of each kind. Ideally I want to use the least amount of time necessary. To start I would use the all trajectory, and then check if it is possible to distinguish the trials with less time.

Comment: @zelite: So basically you have a two-class classification problem with number of features larger than the number of data-points ($N<k$). There are multiple ways to approach this problem, and PCA is rarely a best preprocessing step. You *can* try PCA (treating all your time-points as variables, yes), keep a couple of leading PCs and then do a LDA there, but you can also directly use a regularized LDA, or PLS-LDA, or a support vector machine, or etc. etc.

Comment: @zelite: Also, why don't you simply plot your 40 trials across time in two colours (e.g. unperturbed in blue, and perturbed in red) and see how well they are separated? This would directly show you which time-periods are going to be predictive, and which not.

Answer (score 0):

You need a distance measure between trajectories. It depends on the nature of your process. You could try Mahalanobis on either levels or differences depending on whether your trajectories are stationary or not.

Here's an example. Suppose, your trajectories are not stationary, then first you get the differences:
$$\Delta x_t=x_t-x_{t-1}$$
Next, calculate the covariance matrix using the observations of undisturbed trajectories:
$$C_{ts}=cov[\Delta x_t,\Delta x_s]$$

Note, that you have fewer observations that the length of $\Delta x_t$ vector, therefore, your covariance matrix has a lot of noise. So, you need to regularize it, e.g. using Ledoit-Wolf method.

Once you got regularize covariance matrix $\tilde C_{ts}$, you can plug it into Mahalanobis distance formula:
$$d(\Delta\bar x,\Delta z)= \Delta\bar x\tilde C^{-1}\Delta z'$$
Which gives you a distance between the mean trajectory $\Delta\bar x$ and the given trajectory $\Delta z$. You can train your model to find the threshold distances.

If you want to decide whether the trajectory is disturbed before observing the whole trajectory, then you train your model on the part of a trajectory.